# How do I add an extra column value to a Supabase Vector Store

Tags: supabase, langchain

I want when additions are made to the supabase vectorstore, additions are made to a column titled 'project_id'. However, I have not figure out of way of getting it done. When I add the 'project_id', it is just saved in the metadata row.

However, since multiple people would be uploading to this vector store, I want to be able to filter based on the project id. That is why i want that value to be added when values are being added to the vector store.

This is my current code

```
import { supabaseClient } from '../../../utils/browser-supabase';
import { SupabaseVectorStore } from 'langchain/vectorstores/supabase';
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from 'langchain/embeddings/openai';
import { RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter } from 'langchain/text_splitter';
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';

//need to figure out hwo to add project_ID here
export async function handleVectorStoreUpload({ token, text, project_id }) {
  console.log(token);
  const textSplitter = new RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter({
    chunkSize: 200,
    chunkOverlap: 50,
  });
  const metadata = { project_id: project_id };
  const docs = await textSplitter.createDocuments([text]);

  try {
    const supabase = await supabaseClient(token);
    const vectorStore = await SupabaseVectorStore.fromDocuments(
      docs,
      new OpenAIEmbeddings({
        openAIApiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY,
      }),
      {
        client: supabase,
        tableName: 'documents',
        queryName: 'match_documents',
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading to vector store:', error);
  }
}
```

This is also a screenshot of my vectorstore [The project_id column is empty. How do i had a value to that column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZY6W.png)

Comment: const metadata = [{ "project_id": project_id }];

Comment: @ZKS I have changed that. How do i pass the metadata to the vector stor

Answer (score 0):

This sample code generating embeddings, I have the changed the parameter to project_id so that you can easily understand.

```
    async function generateEmbeddings(text, projed_id) {
      const textSplitter = new RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter({
        chunkSize: 1000,
        chunkOverlap: 200,
      });
      const documents = await textSplitter.createDocuments([text]);
      console.log(documents);

      const content = documents.map((doc) => doc.pageContent).join('\n');
      const metadata = { project_id : project_id };
      const docs = [new Document({ pageContent: content, metadata })];

      let vectorStore = await SupabaseVectorStore.fromDocuments(
        docs,
        new OpenAIEmbeddings(),
        {
          client: SUPABASE_CLIENT,
          tableName: 'documents',
        }
      );
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response. 

When i write this code, i get this error: 

```
app-index.js:32 Error uploading to vector store: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replaceAll')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/langchain/dist/embeddings/openai.js:128:127)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OpenAIEmbeddings.embedDocuments (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/langchain/dist/embeddings/openai.js:128:114)
```

To give some more content, the information is passed in via an input field. The text could be very long.